# Why should wait() always be called inside a loop

Tags: java, multithreading

I have read that we should always call a `wait()` from within a loop:

```
while (!condition) { obj.wait(); }
```

It works fine without a loop so why is that?

Comment: Note:   Oracle documentation calls this idiom a "guarded block"  https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/concurrency/guardmeth.html

Comment: It only works "fine" in a loop in trivial cases.  The rest of the time, your program is subtly broken.  See chapter 14 of _Java Concurrency in Practice_ for examples of what can go wrong.

Answer (score 80):

You need not only to loop it but check your condition in the loop. Java does not guarantee that your thread will be woken up only by a notify()/notifyAll() call or the right notify()/notifyAll() call at all. Because of this property the loop-less version might work on your development environment and fail on the production environment unexpectedly.

For example, you are waiting for something:

```
synchronized (theObjectYouAreWaitingOn) {
   while (!carryOn) {
      theObjectYouAreWaitingOn.wait();
   }
}
```

An evil thread comes along and:

```
theObjectYouAreWaitingOn.notifyAll();
```

If the evil thread does not/can not mess with the `carryOn` you just continue to wait for the proper client.

**Edit:** Added some more samples. 
The wait can be interrupted. It throws InterruptedException and you might need to wrap the wait in a try-catch. Depending on your business needs, you can exit or suppress the exception and continue waiting.

Comment: This is the correct answer. The documentation for wait:
http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/Object.html#wait(long)
... actually describes why you need to put it in a loop - spurious wakeups. Did the OP read it?

Comment: Ah, 'spurious wakeups'. Could not remember the name.

Comment: You should update your code example to handle the ThreadInterruptedException on your wait.  It would then be consistent with your answer.

Comment: Don't know. Adding the try-catch for InterruptedException seemed pointless as it depends on the business logic what you want to do in case of the thread interruptions. Probably you would just exit, or suppress it immediately inside the loop.

Comment: @AndrewDuffy I tried to include that point in my answer...but no one seem to have read it :(

Answer (score 41):

It's answered in [documentation for Object.wait(long milis)](http://java.sun.com/j2se/1.5.0/docs/api/java/lang/Object.html#wait(long))

> A thread can also wake up without being notified, interrupted, or timing out, a so-called spurious wakeup. While this will rarely occur in practice, applications must guard against it by testing for the condition that should have caused the thread to be awakened, and continuing to wait if the condition is not satisfied. In other words, waits should always occur in loops, like this one:

```
 synchronized (obj) {
     while (<condition does not hold>)
         obj.wait(timeout);
     ... // Perform action appropriate to condition
 }
```

> (For more information on this topic,
>   see Section 3.2.3 in Doug Lea's
>   "Concurrent Programming in Java
>   (Second Edition)" (Addison-Wesley,
>   2000), or Item 50 in Joshua Bloch's
>   "Effective Java Programming Language
>   Guide" (Addison-Wesley, 2001).

Answer (score 18):

> Why should wait() always be called inside a loop

The primary reason why `while` loops are so important is race conditions between threads.  Certainly spurious wakeups are real and for certain architectures they are common, but race conditions are a much more likely reason for the `while` loop.

For example:

```
synchronized (queue) {
    // this needs to be while
    while (queue.isEmpty()) {
       queue.wait();
    }
    queue.remove();
}
```

With the above code, there may be 2 consumer threads.  When the producer locks the `queue` to add to it, consumer #1 may be blocked at the `synchronized` lock while consumer #2 is waiting on the `queue`.  When the item is added to the queue and `notify` called by the producer, #2 is moved from the wait queue to be blocked on the `queue` lock, but it will be *behind* the #1 consumer which was already blocked on the lock.  This means that the #1 consumer gets to go forward first to call `remove()` from the `queue`.  If the `while` loop is just an `if`, then when consumer #2 gets the lock after #1 and calls `remove()`, an exception would occur because the `queue` is now empty -- the other consumer thread already removed the item.  Even though it was notified, it needs to be make sure the `queue` is for sure not empty because of this race condition.

This well documented.  Here's a web page I created a while back which explains the [race condition in detail](http://256stuff.com/gray/docs/misc/producer_consumer_race_conditions/) and has some sample code.

Comment: Shouldn't that be `while (queue.isEmpty())` without `!` ?

Comment: how come consumer 1  can be considered to  remove from the queue unless the consumer 2 has exited the synchronized block. notify is anyway going to notify the consumer 2 and consumer 1 will remain  idle.

Comment: Consumer #1 remains idle but is still waiting for the lock.  When consume #2 gets notified, it doesn't run immediately because it needs the lock so it goes into the same wait queue but _behind_ #1 @jayendrabhatt.

Comment: You say "Just because it was notified, it needs to be make sure the queue is still empty because of this race condition". I think "is still empty" should be "is still not empty".

Answer (score 14):

There might be more then just one worker waiting for a condition to become true.

If two or more worker get awake (notifyAll) they have to check the condition again.
otherwise all workers would continue even though there might only be data for one of them.

Answer (score 10):

I think I got @Gray 's answer.

Let me try to rephrase that for newbies like me and request the experts to correct me if I am wrong.

**Consumer synchronized block:**:

```
synchronized (queue) {
    // this needs to be while
    while (queue.isEmpty()) {
       queue.wait();
    }
    queue.remove();
}
```

**Producer synchronized block:**:

```
synchronized(queue) {
 // producer produces inside the queue
    queue.notify();
}
```

Assume the following happens in the given order:

1) consumer#2 gets inside the consumer `synchronized` block and is waiting since queue is empty.

2) Now, producer obtains the lock on `queue`and inserts inside the queue and calls notify().

Now,either consumer#1 can be chosen to run which is waiting for `queue` lock to enter the `synchronized` block for the first time

or

consumer#2 can be chosen to run.

3) say, consumer#1 is chosen to continue with the execution. When it checks the condition,it will be true and it will `remove()` from the queue.

4) say,consumer#2 is proceeding from where it halted its execution (the line after the `wait()` method). If 'while' condition is not there (instead an `if` condition), it will just proceed to call `remove()` which might result in an exception/unexpected behaviour.

Comment: How can two threads be inside a synchronized block at the same time?

Comment: @SudhansuKumar When the thread calls `wait()` it relinquishes its lock on the monitor. See the documentation for Object.wait().

Answer (score 6):

Because wait and notify are used to implement [condition variables](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Monitor_(synchronization)#Blocking_condition_variables) and so you need to check whether the specific predicate you're waiting on is true before continuing.

Comment: kd304 is correct - it is not just that a condition may not have been met - it is the fact that a thread can spuriously wake up from a wait

Comment: @oxbow_lakes As far a the thread waiting on a condition is concerned, there is no real difference between a spurious wake-up and a notify meant to signal a different condition. Either way, you have to check your predicate.

Answer (score 3):

Both safety and liveness  are concerns when using the wait/notify mechanism. The safety property requires that all objects maintain consistent states in a multithreaded environment. The liveness property requires that every operation or method invocation execute to completion without interruption.

To guarantee liveness, programs must test the while loop condition before invoking the wait() method. This early test checks whether another thread has already satisfied the condition predicate and sent a notification. Invoking the wait() method after the notification has been sent results in indefinite blocking.

To guarantee safety, programs must test the while loop condition after returning from the wait() method. Although wait() is intended to block indefinitely until a notification is received, it still must be encased within a loop to prevent the following vulnerabilities:

**Thread in the middle:** A third thread can acquire the lock on the shared object during the interval between a notification being sent and the receiving thread resuming execution. This third thread can change the state of the object, leaving it inconsistent. This is a time-of-check, time-of-use (TOCTOU) race condition.

**Malicious notification:** A random or malicious notification can be received when the condition predicate is false. Such a notification would cancel the wait() method.

**Misdelivered notification:** The order in which threads execute after receipt of a notifyAll() signal is unspecified. Consequently, an unrelated thread could start executing and discover that its condition predicate is satisfied. Consequently, it could resume execution despite being required to remain dormant.

**Spurious wakeups:** Certain Java Virtual Machine (JVM) implementations are vulnerable to spurious wakeups that result in waiting threads waking up even without a notification.

For these reasons, programs must check the condition predicate after the wait() method returns. A while loop is the best choice for checking the condition predicate both before and after invoking wait().

Similarly, the await() method of the Condition interface also must be invoked inside a loop. According to the Java API, Interface Condition

> When waiting upon a Condition, a "spurious wakeup" is permitted to
>   occur, in general, as a concession to the underlying platform
>   semantics. This has little practical impact on most application
>   programs as a Condition should always be waited upon in a loop,
>   testing the state predicate that is being waited for. An
>   implementation is free to remove the possibility of spurious wakeups
>   but it is recommended that applications programmers always assume that
>   they can occur and so always wait in a loop.

New code should use the java.util.concurrent.locks concurrency utilities in place of the wait/notify mechanism. However, legacy code that complies with the other requirements of this rule is permitted to depend on the wait/notify mechanism.

**Noncompliant Code Example**
This noncompliant code example invokes the wait() method inside a traditional if block and fails to check the postcondition after the notification is received. If the notification were accidental or malicious, the thread could wake up prematurely.

```
synchronized (object) {
  if (<condition does not hold>) {
    object.wait();
  }
  // Proceed when condition holds
}
```

**Compliant Solution**
This compliant solution calls the wait() method from within a while loop to check the condition both before and after the call to wait():

```
synchronized (object) {
  while (<condition does not hold>) {
    object.wait();
  }
  // Proceed when condition holds
}
```

Invocations of the java.util.concurrent.locks.Condition.await() method also must be enclosed in a similar loop.

Answer (score 3):

Before getting to the answer, lets see how wait is probably implemented.

```
wait(mutex) {
   // automatically release mutex
   // and go on wait queue

   // ... wait ... wait ... wait ...

   // remove from queue
   // re-acquire mutex
   // exit the wait operation
}
```

In your example `mutex` is the `obj` with the assumption that your code is running inside `synchronized(obj) { }` block.

> A mutex is called as monitor in Java [some subtle differences though]

### A concurrency example using condition variable with `if`

```
synchronized(obj) {
  if (!condition) { 
    obj.wait(); 
  }
  // Do some stuff related to condition
  condition = false;
}
```

Lets say we have 2 threads. **Thread 1** and **Thread 2**.
Lets see some states along the timeline.

### at t = x

**Thread 1 state**:

waiting on `... wait ... wait ... wait ..`

**Thread 2 state**:

Just entered the synchronised section, since as per the thread 1's state, the mutex/monitor is released.

> You can read more about wait() here [java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/Object.html#wait(long)](http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/Object.html#wait(long)).

This is the only thing that is tricky to understand. When 1 thread is inside the synchronized block. Another thread can still enter the synchronized block because wait() causes the monitor/mutex to be released.

Thread 2 is about to read `if (!condition)` statement.

### at t = x + 1

notify() is triggered by some thread on this mutex/monitor.

`condition` becomes `true`

#### Thread 1 state:

Waiting at `re-acquire mutex`, [Since thread-2 has the lock now]

#### Thread 2 state:

Doesn't go inside if condition and marks the `condition = false`.

### at t = x + 2

#### Thread 1 state:

Exits the wait operation and about to mark `condition = false`.

**This state is inconsistent** as `condition` is supposed to be `true` but is `false` already, because **thread 2** marked it `false` previously.

And thats the reason, `while` is required instead of `if`. As `while` would trigger the condition to be checked again for `thread 1` and thread 1 will begin waiting again.

### Result

In order to avoid this inconsistency the correct code seems to be like this:

```
synchronized(obj) {
  while (!condition) { 
    obj.wait(); 
  }
  // Do some stuff related to condition
  condition = false;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

From your Question:

> I have read that we should always called a wait() from within a loop:

Although wait( ) normally waits until notify( ) or notifyAll( ) is called, there is a possibility that in very rare cases the waiting thread could be awakened due to a spurious wakeup. In this case, a waiting thread resumes without notify( ) or notifyAll( ) having been called.

In essence, the thread resumes for no apparent reason.

Because of this remote possibility, Oracle recommends that calls to wait( ) should take place within a loop that checks the condition on which the thread is waiting.

Comment: This answer is wrong. It is not the risk of spurious wakeups that's the reason `wait` should be called in a loop. It's because some other thread may have handled the condition.

Answer (score 0):

Three things you will see people do:

- Using wait without checking anything (BROKEN)
- Using wait with a condition, using an if check first (BROKEN).
- Using wait in a loop, where the loop test checks the condition (NOT BROKEN).

Not appreciating these details about how wait and notify work leads people to choose the wrong approach:

- One is that a thread doesn't remember notifications that happened before it got around to waiting. The notify and notifyAll methods only effect threads that are already waiting, if a thread isn't waiting at the time it is out of luck.
- Another is that a thread releases the lock once it starts waiting. Once it gets a notification it re-acquires the lock and continues on where it left off. Releasing the lock means that thread does not know *anything* about the current state once it wakes back up, any number of other threads could have made changes since then. The check made before the thread started waiting doesn't tell you anything about what the state is currently.

So the first case, with no checking, makes your code vulnerable to race conditions. It might happen to work by accident if one thread has enough of a head start over another. Or you may have threads waiting forever. If you sprinkle in timeouts then you end up with slow code that sometimes doesn't do what you want.

Adding a condition to check apart from the notification itself protects your code from these race conditions and gives your code a way to know what the state is even if the thread wasn't waiting at the right time.

The second case, with if-checks, is likely to work if you have only 2 threads. That puts a limit on the number of states things can get into and when you made faulty assumptions you don't get burned so badly. This is the situation for lots of toy example code exercises. The result is people come away thinking they understand, when they really don't.

Protip: Real world code has more than two threads.

Using the loop lets you re-check the condition once you re-acquire the lock so that you're moving forward based on current state, not on stale state.

Answer (score 0):

If i was able to understand all above you mentioned this part i could not able to understand. In both case if its if block it will goes to wait if there’s while it also gonna waiting state
**And thats the reason, while is required instead of if. As while would trigger the condition to be checked again for thread 1 and thread 1 will begin waiting again.**

Answer (score -1):

In simple words,

'if' is a conditional statement , once condition is satisfied remaining block of code will get executed.

'while' is a loop which going check the condition unless condition  is not satisfied.

Comment: This is not related to the `wait` function

Comment: could you please explain ?, I have answered to why wait() should be called inside the loop