# What causes an java.lang.IllegalMonitorStateException

Tags: java, multithreading

I'm trying to write a code which wants to make a write thread. When I want to run it, I got this exception. Each post that I saw about this topic didn't have the code same as mine. So can any one help me about my problem?

```
java.lang.IllegalMonitorStateException
```

The stacktrace is as below:

```
    at java.lang.Object.wait(Native Method)
    at java.lang.Object.wait(Object.java:485)
    at prj.McWThread.ReadPacket(McWThread.java:40)
    at prj.McWThread.run(McWThread.java:73)
```

The part of code that makes this exception is :

```
public void run()
{
    try{
        while (true)
        {
            this.MyPkt = ReadPacket();
            ByteArrayOutputStream baos = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
            ObjectOutputStream oos = new ObjectOutputStream(baos);
            oos.writeObject(MyPkt);
       }
       }
}
```

Readpacket method:

```
public MyPacket ReadPacket()
{
    MyPacket m = new MyPacket();
    System.out.println("ReadPacket");
    try {
        while (Buff.isEmpty()) {
            wait();
        }
    }
    catch (InterruptedException ie) {
        ie.printStackTrace();
    }

    if (! Buff.isEmpty()) {
        m = (MyPacket) Buff.remove(0);
        return m;
    } else {
        return m;
    }
}
```

Comment: show us your ReadPacket method?

Comment: Grow the habit to read javadoc to the methods you use for the first time.

Comment: I used wait() before and I didn't face this problem. So I didn't think that the problem may be because of this call.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to `synchonize` your call to wait in your code. Two Options:

- Declare your method as syncronised

  public syncronized MyPacket ReadPacket()
- use `synchronized(this)` before your call to `wait`.

The first one may not be advisable depending on your design and the work other threads need to carry out, if any.

For the second option, again, you need to be sure if you would want to use `this` as your monitor. You can create a `Lock` and use that instead.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I use synchronized(this) and it worked.

Answer (score 1):

The javadoc for [Object.wait](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/lang/Object.html#wait%28long%29).

"The current thread must own this object's monitor." and "[throws] IllegalMonitorStateException - if the current thread is not the owner of the object's monitor." 
You need to synchronize on the object you are going to call the wait on.

The code should look something like

```
synchronize(someobject){
   someobject.wait();
}
```

Comment: You should always [wait in a loop](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1038007/why-should-wait-always-be-called-inside-a-loop).

Comment: I'm using wait in a loop, too. (As I post my ReadPacket method above)