# Release lock of a map and grab lock of a value

Tags: java, multithreading, locking

I want to have on object with a method which only prints the numbers which have not been received yet , therefore I used the following code. The idea is that I use a map which for each integer it stores a lock , a thread wait on a lock if it's already in the map, otherwise it will put a new lock into the map with that integer as key and an `Integer` object as the value,

Note : I use `Integer(a)` as the lock for integer `a`

The problem is that I want to release lock of the map and I want to wait on the lock which is retrieved from the map, but a `race condition` happens, any idea to resolve the problem ?

```
public class sync_print {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        sync_print syobj = new sync_print();
        Thread t1 = new Thread(new worker(syobj, 10) , "thread 1");
        Thread t2 = new Thread(new worker(syobj, 10) , "thread 2");
        Thread t3 = new Thread(new worker(syobj, 4) , "thread 3");
        Thread t4 = new Thread(new worker(syobj, 5) , "thread 4");
        Thread t5 = new Thread(new worker(syobj, 5) , "thread 5");
        t1.start();
        t2.start();
        t3.start();
        t4.start();
        t5.start();
    }


    HashMap<Integer, Integer> lock_map = new HashMap<Integer , Integer>();
    void print(int a) throws InterruptedException{
        synchronized(lock_map){
            Integer lock = lock_map.get(a);
            if (lock != null){
                synchronized (lock) {
                    System.out.println(Thread.currentThread().getName() + " is waiting");
                    lock_map.notify();
                    lock.wait();
                }
            }else{
                lock_map.put(a, new Integer(a));
                System.out.println(a);
            }
        }
    }
}

class worker implements Runnable{
    int val;
    sync_print obj;
    public worker(sync_print obj , int v){
        this.val = v;
        this.obj = obj;
    }
    public void run() {
        try {
            obj.print(val);
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {}
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You might be able to eliminate the lock on `lock_map` by replacing your `HashMap` with a [ConcurrentHashMap](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/ConcurrentHashMap.html).  Change `lock_map.put` to `lock_map.putIfAbsent`.

Comment: I don't understand how is it related to the problem , can you elaborate please ?

Comment: @Arian Hosseinzadeh I'm not entirely clear on what your lock on `lock_map` is doing, but if it's there to prevent multiple threads from calling `lock_map.put` at the same time then you can use `ConcurrentHashMap#putIfAbsent` to accomplish this instead - if two threads call `putIfAbsent` at the same time then only one will succeed.

Answer (score 0):

Your `wait` is not inside a loop. See [elsewhere](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1038007/why-should-wait-always-be-called-inside-a-loop) for why that can create problems.