# Java Concurrency: Paired locks with shared access

Tags: java, concurrency

I am looking for a Java implementation of the following concurrency semantics. I want something similar to `ReadWriteLock` except symmetrical, i.e. both the read and write sides can be shared amongst many threads, but read excludes write and *vice versa*.

1. There are two locks, let's call them A and B.
2. Lock A is shared, i.e. there may be multiple threads holding it concurrently. Lock B is also shared, there may be multiple threads holding it concurrently.
3. If *any* thread holds lock A then *no* thread may take B – threads attempting to take B shall block until all threads holding A have released A.
4. If *any* thread holds lock B then *no* thread may take A – threads attempting to take A shall block until all threads holding B have released B.

Is there an existing library class that achieves this? At the moment I have approximated the desired functionality with a `ReadWriteLock` because fortunately the tasks done in the context of lock B are somewhat rarer. It feels like a hack though, and it could affect the performance of my program under heavy load.

Comment: There are a few answers here, but none of them address fairness. Starvation of one side of your lock could be a serious problem, especially if one of the groups runs more frequently than the other (which appears to be your case). If there is always an _A_ running, no _B_ will ever run.

Answer (score 3):

### Short answer:

In the standard library, there is nothing like what you need.

### Long answer:

To easily implement a custom `Lock` you should subclass or delegate to an  [AbstractQueuedSynchronizer](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/locks/AbstractQueuedSynchronizer.html).

The following code is an example of a [non-fair](http://tutorials.jenkov.com/java-concurrency/starvation-and-fairness.html) lock that implements what you need, including some (non exhausting) test. I called it **LeftRightLock** because of the *binary* nature of your requirements.

The concept is pretty straightforward:

`AbstractQueuedSynchronizer` exposes a method to atomically set the state of an `int` using the [Compare and swap](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Compare-and-swap) idiom  ( [compareAndSetState(int expect, int update)](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/locks/AbstractQueuedSynchronizer.html#compareAndSetState(int,%20int)) ), we can use the exposed state keep the count of the threads holding the lock, setting it to a positive value in case the `Right` lock is being held or a negative value in case the `Left` lock is being held.

Than we just make sure of the following conditions:
- you can lock `Left` only if the state of the internal `AbstractQueuedSynchronizer` is `zero` or negative
- you can lock `Right` only if the state of the internal `AbstractQueuedSynchronizer` is `zero` or positive

**LeftRightLock.java**

---

```
import java.util.concurrent.locks.AbstractQueuedSynchronizer;
import java.util.concurrent.locks.Lock;

/**
 * A binary mutex with the following properties:
 *
 * Exposes two different {@link Lock}s: LEFT, RIGHT.
 *
 * When LEFT is held other threads can acquire LEFT but thread trying to acquire RIGHT will be
 * blocked. When RIGHT is held other threads can acquire RIGHT but thread trying to acquire LEFT
 * will be blocked.
 */
public class LeftRightLock {

    public static final int ACQUISITION_FAILED = -1;
    public static final int ACQUISITION_SUCCEEDED = 1;

    private final LeftRightSync sync = new LeftRightSync();

    public void lockLeft() {
        sync.acquireShared(LockSide.LEFT.getV());
    }

    public void lockRight() {
        sync.acquireShared(LockSide.RIGHT.getV());
    }

    public void releaseLeft() {
        sync.releaseShared(LockSide.LEFT.getV());
    }

    public void releaseRight() {
        sync.releaseShared(LockSide.RIGHT.getV());
    }

    public boolean tryLockLeft() {
        return sync.tryAcquireShared(LockSide.LEFT) == ACQUISITION_SUCCEEDED;
    }

    public boolean tryLockRight() {
        return sync.tryAcquireShared(LockSide.RIGHT) == ACQUISITION_SUCCEEDED;
    }

    private enum LockSide {
        LEFT(-1), NONE(0), RIGHT(1);

        private final int v;

        LockSide(int v) {
            this.v = v;
        }

        public int getV() {
            return v;
        }
    }

    /**
     * <p>
     * Keep count the count of threads holding either the LEFT or the RIGHT lock.
     * </p>
     *
     * <li>A state ({@link AbstractQueuedSynchronizer#getState()}) greater than 0 means one or more threads are holding RIGHT lock. </li>
     * <li>A state ({@link AbstractQueuedSynchronizer#getState()}) lower than 0 means one or more threads are holding LEFT lock.</li>
     * <li>A state ({@link AbstractQueuedSynchronizer#getState()}) equal to zero means no thread is holding any lock.</li>
     */
    private static final class LeftRightSync extends AbstractQueuedSynchronizer {


        @Override
        protected int tryAcquireShared(int requiredSide) {
            return (tryChangeThreadCountHoldingCurrentLock(requiredSide, ChangeType.ADD) ? ACQUISITION_SUCCEEDED : ACQUISITION_FAILED);
        }    

        @Override
        protected boolean tryReleaseShared(int requiredSide) {
            return tryChangeThreadCountHoldingCurrentLock(requiredSide, ChangeType.REMOVE);
        }

        public boolean tryChangeThreadCountHoldingCurrentLock(int requiredSide, ChangeType changeType) {
            if (requiredSide != 1 && requiredSide != -1)
                throw new AssertionError("You can either lock LEFT or RIGHT (-1 or +1)");

            int curState;
            int newState;
            do {
                curState = this.getState();
                if (!sameSide(curState, requiredSide)) {
                    return false;
                }

                if (changeType == ChangeType.ADD) {
                    newState = curState + requiredSide;
                } else {
                    newState = curState - requiredSide;
                }
                //TODO: protect against int overflow (hopefully you won't have so many threads)
            } while (!this.compareAndSetState(curState, newState));
            return true;
        }    

        final int tryAcquireShared(LockSide lockSide) {
            return this.tryAcquireShared(lockSide.getV());
        }

        final boolean tryReleaseShared(LockSide lockSide) {
            return this.tryReleaseShared(lockSide.getV());
        }

        private boolean sameSide(int curState, int requiredSide) {
            return curState == 0 || sameSign(curState, requiredSide);
        }

        private boolean sameSign(int a, int b) {
            return (a >= 0) ^ (b < 0);
        }

        public enum ChangeType {
            ADD, REMOVE
        }
    }
}
```

**LeftRightLockTest.java**

---

```
import org.junit.Test;

import java.util.concurrent.CountDownLatch;
import java.util.concurrent.Executors;
import java.util.concurrent.Future;

import static org.junit.Assert.assertFalse;
import static org.junit.Assert.assertTrue;

public class LeftRightLockTest {


    int logLineSequenceNumber = 0;
    private LeftRightLock sut = new LeftRightLock();

    @Test(timeout = 2000)
    public void acquiringLeftLockExcludeAcquiringRightLock() throws Exception {
        sut.lockLeft();


        Future<Boolean> task = Executors.newSingleThreadExecutor().submit(() -> sut.tryLockRight());
        assertFalse("I shouldn't be able to acquire the RIGHT lock!", task.get());
    }

    @Test(timeout = 2000)
    public void acquiringRightLockExcludeAcquiringLeftLock() throws Exception {
        sut.lockRight();
        Future<Boolean> task = Executors.newSingleThreadExecutor().submit(() -> sut.tryLockLeft());
        assertFalse("I shouldn't be able to acquire the LEFT lock!", task.get());
    }

    @Test(timeout = 2000)
    public void theLockShouldBeReentrant() throws Exception {
        sut.lockLeft();
        assertTrue(sut.tryLockLeft());
    }

    @Test(timeout = 2000)
    public void multipleThreadShouldBeAbleToAcquireTheSameLock_Right() throws Exception {
        sut.lockRight();
        Future<Boolean> task = Executors.newSingleThreadExecutor().submit(() -> sut.tryLockRight());
        assertTrue(task.get());
    }

    @Test(timeout = 2000)
    public void multipleThreadShouldBeAbleToAcquireTheSameLock_left() throws Exception {
        sut.lockLeft();
        Future<Boolean> task = Executors.newSingleThreadExecutor().submit(() -> sut.tryLockLeft());
        assertTrue(task.get());
    }

    @Test(timeout = 2000)
    public void shouldKeepCountOfAllTheThreadsHoldingTheSide() throws Exception {

        CountDownLatch latchA = new CountDownLatch(1);
        CountDownLatch latchB = new CountDownLatch(1);


        Thread threadA = spawnThreadToAcquireLeftLock(latchA, sut);
        Thread threadB = spawnThreadToAcquireLeftLock(latchB, sut);

        System.out.println("Both threads have acquired the left lock.");

        try {
            latchA.countDown();
            threadA.join();
            boolean acqStatus = sut.tryLockRight();
            System.out.println("The right lock was " + (acqStatus ? "" : "not") + " acquired");
            assertFalse("There is still a thread holding the left lock. This shouldn't succeed.", acqStatus);
        } finally {
            latchB.countDown();
            threadB.join();
        }

    }

    @Test(timeout = 5000)
    public void shouldBlockThreadsTryingToAcquireLeftIfRightIsHeld() throws Exception {
        sut.lockLeft();

        CountDownLatch taskStartedLatch = new CountDownLatch(1);

        final Future<Boolean> task = Executors.newSingleThreadExecutor().submit(() -> {
            taskStartedLatch.countDown();
            sut.lockRight();
            return false;
        });

        taskStartedLatch.await();
        Thread.sleep(100);

        assertFalse(task.isDone());
    }

    @Test
    public void shouldBeFreeAfterRelease() throws Exception {
        sut.lockLeft();
        sut.releaseLeft();
        assertTrue(sut.tryLockRight());
    }

    @Test
    public void shouldBeFreeAfterMultipleThreadsReleaseIt() throws Exception {
        CountDownLatch latch = new CountDownLatch(1);

        final Thread thread1 = spawnThreadToAcquireLeftLock(latch, sut);
        final Thread thread2 = spawnThreadToAcquireLeftLock(latch, sut);

        latch.countDown();

        thread1.join();
        thread2.join();

        assertTrue(sut.tryLockRight());

    }

    @Test(timeout = 2000)
    public void lockShouldBeReleasedIfNoThreadIsHoldingIt() throws Exception {
        CountDownLatch releaseLeftLatch = new CountDownLatch(1);
        CountDownLatch rightLockTaskIsRunning = new CountDownLatch(1);

        Thread leftLockThread1 = spawnThreadToAcquireLeftLock(releaseLeftLatch, sut);
        Thread leftLockThread2 = spawnThreadToAcquireLeftLock(releaseLeftLatch, sut);

        Future<Boolean> acquireRightLockTask = Executors.newSingleThreadExecutor().submit(() -> {
            if (sut.tryLockRight())
                throw new AssertionError("The left lock should be still held, I shouldn't be able to acquire right a this point.");
            printSynchronously("Going to be blocked on right lock");
            rightLockTaskIsRunning.countDown();
            sut.lockRight();
            printSynchronously("Lock acquired!");
            return true;
        });

        rightLockTaskIsRunning.await();

        releaseLeftLatch.countDown();
        leftLockThread1.join();
        leftLockThread2.join();

        assertTrue(acquireRightLockTask.get());
    }

    private synchronized void printSynchronously(String str) {

        System.out.println(logLineSequenceNumber++ + ")" + str);
        System.out.flush();
    }

    private Thread spawnThreadToAcquireLeftLock(CountDownLatch releaseLockLatch, LeftRightLock lock) throws InterruptedException {
        CountDownLatch lockAcquiredLatch = new CountDownLatch(1);
        final Thread thread = spawnThreadToAcquireLeftLock(releaseLockLatch, lockAcquiredLatch, lock);
        lockAcquiredLatch.await();
        return thread;
    }

    private Thread spawnThreadToAcquireLeftLock(CountDownLatch releaseLockLatch, CountDownLatch lockAcquiredLatch, LeftRightLock lock) {
        final Thread thread = new Thread(() -> {
            lock.lockLeft();
            printSynchronously("Thread " + Thread.currentThread() + " Acquired left lock");
            try {
                lockAcquiredLatch.countDown();
                releaseLockLatch.await();
            } catch (InterruptedException ignore) {
            } finally {
                lock.releaseLeft();
            }

            printSynchronously("Thread " + Thread.currentThread() + " RELEASED left lock");
        });
        thread.start();
        return thread;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I don't know any library that does that you want. Even if there is such a library it possess little value because every time your request changes the library stops doing the magic.

The actual question here is "How to I implement my own lock with custom specification?"

Java provides tool for that named [`AbstractQueuedSynchronizer`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/locks/AbstractQueuedSynchronizer.html). It has extensive documentation. Apart from docs one would possibly like to look at `CountDownLatch` and `ReentrantLock` sources and use them as examples.

For your particular request see code below, but beware that it is 1) not fair 2) not tested

```
public class MultiReadWriteLock implements ReadWriteLock {

    private final Sync sync;
    private final Lock readLock;
    private final Lock writeLock;

    public MultiReadWriteLock() {
        this.sync = new Sync();
        this.readLock = new MultiLock(Sync.READ, sync);
        this.writeLock = new MultiLock(Sync.WRITE, sync);
    }

    @Override
    public Lock readLock() {
        return readLock;
    }

    @Override
    public Lock writeLock() {
        return writeLock;
    }

    private static final class Sync extends AbstractQueuedSynchronizer {

        private static final int READ = 1;
        private static final int WRITE = -1;

        @Override
        public int tryAcquireShared(int arg) {
            int state, result;
            do {
                state = getState();
                if (state >= 0 && arg == READ) {
                    // new read
                    result = state + 1;
                } else if (state <= 0 && arg == WRITE) {
                    // new write
                    result = state - 1;
                } else {
                    // blocked
                    return -1;
                }
            } while (!compareAndSetState(state, result));
            return 1;
        }

        @Override
        protected boolean tryReleaseShared(int arg) {
            int state, result;
            do {
                state = getState();
                if (state == 0) {
                    return false;
                }
                if (state > 0 && arg == READ) {
                    result = state - 1;
                } else if (state < 0 && arg == WRITE) {
                    result = state + 1;
                } else {
                    throw new IllegalMonitorStateException();
                }
            } while (!compareAndSetState(state, result));
            return result == 0;
        }
    }

    private static class MultiLock implements Lock {

        private final int parameter;
        private final Sync sync;

        public MultiLock(int parameter, Sync sync) {
            this.parameter = parameter;
            this.sync = sync;
        }

        @Override
        public void lock() {
            sync.acquireShared(parameter);
        }

        @Override
        public void lockInterruptibly() throws InterruptedException {
            sync.acquireSharedInterruptibly(parameter);
        }

        @Override
        public boolean tryLock() {
            return sync.tryAcquireShared(parameter) > 0;
        }

        @Override
        public boolean tryLock(long time, TimeUnit unit) throws InterruptedException {
            return sync.tryAcquireSharedNanos(parameter, unit.toNanos(time));
        }

        @Override
        public void unlock() {
            sync.releaseShared(parameter);
        }

        @Override
        public Condition newCondition() {
            throw new UnsupportedOperationException(
                "Conditions are unsupported as there are no exclusive access"
            );
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

How about

```
class ABSync {

    private int aHolders;
    private int bHolders;

    public synchronized void lockA() throws InterruptedException {
        while (bHolders > 0) {
            wait();
        }
        aHolders++;
    }

    public synchronized void lockB() throws InterruptedException {
        while (aHolders > 0) {
            wait();
        }
        bHolders++;
    }

    public synchronized void unlockA() {
        aHolders = Math.max(0, aHolders - 1);
        if (aHolders == 0) {
            notifyAll();
        }
    }

    public synchronized void unlockB() {
        bHolders = Math.max(0, bHolders - 1);
        if (bHolders == 0) {
            notifyAll();
        }
    }
}
```

**Update:** As for "fairness" (or, rather, non-starvation), OPs requirements don't mention it. In order to implement OPs requirements + some form of fairness/non-starvation, it should be specified explicitly (what do you consider fair, how should it behave when flows of requests for currently dominant and non-dominant locks come in etc). One of the ways to implement it would be:

```
class ABMoreFairSync {

    private Lock lock = new ReentrantLock(true);
    public final Part A, B;

    public ABMoreFairSync() {
        A = new Part();
        B = new Part();
        A.other = B;
        B.other = A;
    }

    private class Part {
        private Condition canGo = lock.newCondition();
        private int currentGeneration, lastGeneration;
        private int holders;
        private Part other;

        public void lock() throws InterruptedException {
            lock.lockInterruptibly();
            try {
                int myGeneration = lastGeneration;
                if (other.holders > 0 || currentGeneration < myGeneration) {
                    if (other.currentGeneration == other.lastGeneration) {
                        other.lastGeneration++;
                    }
                    while (other.holders > 0 || currentGeneration < myGeneration) {
                        canGo.await();
                    }
                }
                holders++;
            } finally {
                lock.unlock();
            }
        }

        public void unlock() throws InterruptedException {
            lock.lockInterruptibly();
            try {
                holders = Math.max(0, holders - 1);
                if (holders == 0) {
                    currentGeneration++;
                    other.canGo.signalAll();
                }
            } finally {
                lock.unlock();
            }
        }
    }
}
```

To be used as in:

```
 sync.A.lock();
 try {
     ...
 } finally {
     sync.A.unlock();
 }
```

The idea of generations here is taken from "Java Concurrency in Practice", [Listing 14.9](http://jcip.net/listings/ThreadGate.java).

Comment: your code may contain infinite loops after compiler optimization. use `volatile` variables to avoid it

Comment: @SergeyFedorov could you elaborate a bit please? I really thought my usage of `synchronized` was enough for correctness

Comment: non-volatile field read can be cached (by JIT, for instance). If your `aHolders` will be cached in locked state you'll get an infinite loop

Comment: @SergeyFedorov the synchronized block will force a memory barrier either side of the test. The while loop will work, and is in fact [good practice](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1038007/why-should-wait-always-be-called-inside-a-loop).

Comment: @teppic that's true but caching problem still remains

Comment: @SergeyFedorov any compiler that optimises out a monitor lock is fundamentally broken

Comment: `lockB` will never return if there is always one thread keeping a `lockA` (in which case `aHolders` never reaches `0` and `bHolders++` is never executed). I like the simplicity of the code but it needs a part that decides when to prioritize lock-request for lock B over lock requests for lock A and vice versa.

Answer (score 0):

After my *n*th attempt to make a simple fair implementation, I think I understand why I could not find another library/example of the "mutual exclusive lock-pair": it requires a pretty specific user-case. As OP mentioned, you can get a long way with the ReadWriteLock and a fair lock-pair is only useful when there are many requests for a lock in quick succession (else you might as well use one normal lock).

The implementation below is more of a "permit dispenser": it is not re-entrant. It can be made re-entrant though (if not, I fear I failed to make the code simple and readable) but it requires some additional administration for various cases (e.g. one thread locking A twice, still needs to unlock A twice and the unlock-method needs to know when there are no more locks outstanding). An option to throw a deadlock error when one thread locks A and wants to lock B is probably a good idea.

The main idea is that there is an "active lock" that can only be changed by the lock-method when there are no (requests for) locks at all and can be changed by the unlock-method when the active locks outstanding reaches zero. The rest is basically keeping count of lock-requests and making threads wait until the active lock can be changed. Making threads wait involves working with `InterruptedException`s and I made a compromise there: I could not find a good solution that works well in all cases (e.g. application shutdown, one thread that gets interrupted, etc.).

I only did some basic testing (test class at the end), more validation is needed.

```
import java.util.concurrent.Semaphore;
import java.util.concurrent.locks.ReentrantLock;

/**
 * A pair of mutual exclusive read-locks: many threads can hold a lock for A or B, but never A and B.
 * <br>Usage:<pre>
 * PairedLock plock = new PairedLock();
 * plock.lockA();
 * try {
 *     // do stuff
 * } finally {
 *     plock.unlockA();
 * }</pre>
 * This lock is not reentrant: a lock is not associated with a thread and a thread asking for the same lock 
 * might be blocked the second time (potentially causing a deadlock).
 * <p> 
 * When a lock for A is active, a lock for B will wait for all locks on A to be unlocked and vice versa.
 * <br>When a lock for A is active, and a lock for B is waiting, subsequent locks for A will wait 
 * until all (waiting) locks for B are unlocked.
 * I.e. locking is fair (in FIFO order).
 * <p>
 * See also
 * <a href="http://stackoverflow.com/questions/41358436">stackoverflow-java-concurrency-paired-locks-with-shared-access</a>
 * 
 * @author vanOekel
 *
 */
public class PairedLock {

    static final int MAX_LOCKS = 2;
    static final int CLOSE_PERMITS = 10_000;

    /** Use a fair lock to keep internal state instead of the {@code synchronized} keyword. */
    final ReentrantLock state = new ReentrantLock(true);

    /** Amount of threads that have locks. */
    final int[] activeLocks = new int[MAX_LOCKS];

    /** Amount of threads waiting to receive a lock. */
    final int[] waitingLocks = new int[MAX_LOCKS];

    /** Threads block on a semaphore until locks are available. */
    final Semaphore[] waiters = new Semaphore[MAX_LOCKS];

    int activeLock;
    volatile boolean closed;

    public PairedLock() {
        super();
        for (int i = 0; i < MAX_LOCKS; i++) {
            // no need for fair semaphore: unlocks are done for all in one go.
            waiters[i] = new Semaphore(0);
        }
    }

    public void lockA() throws InterruptedException { lock(0); }
    public void lockB() throws InterruptedException { lock(1); }

    public void lock(int lockNumber) throws InterruptedException {

        if (lockNumber < 0 || lockNumber >= MAX_LOCKS) {
            throw new IllegalArgumentException("Lock number must be 0 or less than " + MAX_LOCKS);
        } else if (isClosed()) {
            throw new IllegalStateException("Lock closed.");
        }
        boolean wait = false;
        state.lock();
        try {
            if (nextLockIsWaiting()) {
                wait = true;
            } else if (activeLock == lockNumber) {
                activeLocks[activeLock]++;
            } else if (activeLock != lockNumber && activeLocks[activeLock] == 0) {
                // nothing active and nobody waiting - safe to switch to another active lock
                activeLock = lockNumber;
                activeLocks[activeLock]++;
            } else {
                // with only two locks this means this is the first lock that needs an active-lock switch.
                // in other words:
                // activeLock != lockNumber && activeLocks[activeLock] > 0 && waitingLocks[lockNumber] == 0
                wait = true;
            }
            if (wait) {
                waitingLocks[lockNumber]++;
            }
        } finally {
            state.unlock();
        }
        if (wait) {
            waiters[lockNumber].acquireUninterruptibly();
            // there is no easy way to bring this lock back into a valid state when waiters do no get a lock.
            // so for now, use the closed state to make this lock unusable any further.
            if (closed) {
                throw new InterruptedException("Lock closed.");
            }
        }
    }

    protected boolean nextLockIsWaiting() {
        return (waitingLocks[nextLock(activeLock)] > 0);
    }

    protected int nextLock(int lockNumber) {
        return (lockNumber == 0 ? 1 : 0);
    }

    public void unlockA() { unlock(0); }
    public void unlockB() { unlock(1); }

    public void unlock(int lockNumber) {

        // unlock is called in a finally-block and should never throw an exception.
        if (lockNumber < 0 || lockNumber >= MAX_LOCKS) {
            System.out.println("Cannot unlock lock number " + lockNumber);
            return;
        }
        state.lock();
        try {
            if (activeLock != lockNumber) {
                System.out.println("ERROR: invalid lock state: no unlocks for inactive lock expected (active: " + activeLock + ", unlock: " + lockNumber + ").");
                return;
            }
            activeLocks[lockNumber]--;
            if (activeLocks[activeLock] == 0 && nextLockIsWaiting()) {
                activeLock = nextLock(lockNumber);
                waiters[activeLock].release(waitingLocks[activeLock]);
                activeLocks[activeLock] += waitingLocks[activeLock];
                waitingLocks[activeLock] = 0;
            } else if (activeLocks[lockNumber] < 0) {
                System.out.println("ERROR: to many unlocks for lock number " + lockNumber);
                activeLocks[lockNumber] = 0;
            }
        } finally {
            state.unlock();
        }
    }

    public boolean isClosed() { return closed; }

    /**
     * All threads waiting for a lock will be unblocked and an {@link InterruptedException} will be thrown.
     * Subsequent calls to the lock-method will throw an {@link IllegalStateException}.
     */
    public synchronized void close() {

        if (!closed) {
            closed = true;
            for (int i = 0; i < MAX_LOCKS; i++) {
                waiters[i].release(CLOSE_PERMITS);
            }
        }
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {

        StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder(this.getClass().getSimpleName());
        sb.append("=").append(this.hashCode());
        state.lock();
        try {
            sb.append(", active=").append(activeLock).append(", switching=").append(nextLockIsWaiting());
            sb.append(", lockA=").append(activeLocks[0]).append("/").append(waitingLocks[0]);
            sb.append(", lockB=").append(activeLocks[1]).append("/").append(waitingLocks[1]);
        } finally {
            state.unlock();
        }
        return sb.toString();
    }

}
```

The test class (YMMV - works fine on my system, but may deadlock on yours due to faster or slower starting and running of threads):

```
import java.util.concurrent.CountDownLatch;
import java.util.concurrent.Executors;
import java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor;

import org.slf4j.Logger;
import org.slf4j.LoggerFactory;

public class PairedLockTest {

    private static final Logger log = LoggerFactory.getLogger(PairedLockTest.class);

    public static final ThreadPoolExecutor tp = (ThreadPoolExecutor) Executors.newCachedThreadPool();

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        try {
            new PairedLockTest().test();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } finally {
            tp.shutdownNow();
        }
    }

    PairedLock mlock = new PairedLock();

    public void test() throws InterruptedException {

        CountDownLatch start = new CountDownLatch(1);
        CountDownLatch done = new CountDownLatch(2);
        mlock.lockA();
        try {
            logLock("la1 ");
            mlock.lockA();
            try {
                lockAsync(start, null, done, 1);
                await(start);
                logLock("la2 ");
            } finally {
                mlock.unlockA();
            }
            lockAsync(null, null, done, 0);
        } finally {
            mlock.unlockA();
        }
        await(done);
        logLock();
    }

    void lockAsync(CountDownLatch start, CountDownLatch locked, CountDownLatch unlocked, int lockNumber) {

        tp.execute(() -> {
            countDown(start);
            await(start);
            //log.info("Locking async " + lockNumber);
            try {
                mlock.lock(lockNumber);
                try {
                    countDown(locked);
                    logLock("async " + lockNumber + " ");
                } finally {
                    mlock.unlock(lockNumber);
                    //log.info("Unlocked async " + lockNumber);
                    //logLock("async " + lockNumber + " ");
                }
                countDown(unlocked);
            } catch (InterruptedException ie) {
                log.warn(ie.toString());
            }
        });
    }

    void logLock() {
        logLock("");
    }

    void logLock(String msg) {
        log.info(msg + mlock.toString());
    }

    static void countDown(CountDownLatch l) {
        if (l != null) {
            l.countDown();
        }
    }

    static void await(CountDownLatch l) {

        if (l == null) {
            return;
        }
        try {
            l.await();
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
            log.error(e.toString(), e.getCause());
        }
    }

}
```