# Multithreaded program never stops executing

Tags: java, eclipse, multithreading, quicksort

I have a multithreaded quicksort algorithm witch runs correct but then never stops executing.

I tried adding return statemants everywhere but nothing helps.

How do I stop all thread from running when they are done? Is there a way for a thread terminate its self when done?

```
public class Parallel {
    private static final int numberOfThreads = Runtime.getRuntime().availableProcessors();
    private static final int fallback = 2;
    private static Executor pool = Executors.newFixedThreadPool(numberOfThreads);
    //public static int[] numberArray;


    public static <T extends Comparable<T>> void sort(int[] numberArray){

        if(numberArray == null || numberArray.length == 0){
          return;
        }

        final AtomicInteger count = new AtomicInteger(1);
        pool.execute(new QuicksortRunnable<T>(numberArray, 0, numberArray.length-1, count));

        try {
          synchronized (count) {
            count.wait();

          }
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {       
          e.printStackTrace();
        }
      }

    private static class QuicksortRunnable<T extends Comparable<T>> implements Runnable {
        private final int[] values;
        private final int left;
        private final int right;
        private final AtomicInteger count;

        public QuicksortRunnable(int[] values, int left, int right, AtomicInteger count) {
          this.values = values;
          this.left = left;
          this.right = right;
          this.count = count;
        }

        @Override
        public void run() {
          quicksort(left, right);
          synchronized (count) {
            // AtomicInteger.getAndDecrement() returns the old value. If the old value is 1, then we know that the actual value is 0.
            if (count.getAndDecrement() == 1)
                count.notify();                         
          }
          return;
        }

        private void quicksort(int pLeft, int pRight) {

          int pivotIndex = (pRight - pLeft) / 2 + pLeft;
          int pivot = values[pivotIndex];
          int j = pRight;
          int i = pLeft;

          while (i < j) {
            while (values[i] > pivot) {
              i++;
            }

            while (values[j] < pivot) {
              j--;
            }

            if (i <= j) {
              int temp = values[i];
              values[i] = values[j];
              values[j] = temp;
              i++;
              j--;
            }
          }

          if (count.get() >= fallback * numberOfThreads) {
            if (pLeft < j){

              quicksort(pLeft, j);
            }
            if (i < pRight) {

              quicksort(i, pRight);
            }
          } else {
            if (pLeft < j) {

              count.getAndAdd(1);
              pool.execute(new QuicksortRunnable<T>(values, pLeft, j, count));
            }
            if (i < pRight) {

              count.getAndAdd(1);
              pool.execute(new QuicksortRunnable<T>(values, i, pRight, count));
            }
          }
        }

      }
```

And my Main function

```
 public static void main(String args[]) {
        Random rand = new Random();
        int length = 100000;

        int[] parallelArray = new int[length];

        for (int i = 0; i < length; i++) {
            int temp = rand.nextInt(length);
            parallelArray[i] = temp;            
        }
        sort(parallelArray);
        boolean t = check(parallelArray);
        System.out.println(t);
    }
```

Function to test if code is sorted.

```
public static boolean check(int[] A) {
        for (int i = 0; i < A.length - 1; i++) {
            // System.out.print(" " + A[i]);
            if (A[i] < A[i + 1]) {
                return false;
            }
        }
        return true;
    }
```

Comment: `synchronized (count) { count.wait();` you grab the lock and hold it, your threads never get a chance to do work. Your main thread should just return after submitting the work to the thread pool.

Comment: count.wait() releases the lock. Consider also to use a while loop because the jvm can awake some threads sometimes (https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1038007/why-should-wait-always-be-called-inside-a-loop). Consider also using a ForkJoinPool with ForkJoinPool.commonPool() (https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/ForkJoinPool.html#commonPool--)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you use a `ExecutorService` you need to call the `ExecutorService.shutdown()` after all tasks are submitted, then you need to wait for the pool to shut down by calling `ExecutorService.awaitTermination()` and supply the time to wait as parameters. This is because the pool is comprised of non-daemon threads and the jvm does not exit if there are non-daemon threads still running.

So change the this to use the `ExecutorService` from `Executor` to enable hooks:

```
private static ExecutorService pool = Executors.newFixedThreadPool(numberOfThreads);
```

Then call `shutdown()` in the `finally` block:

```
public static <T extends Comparable<T>> void sort(int[] numberArray) {

        if (numberArray == null || numberArray.length == 0) {
            return;
        }

        final AtomicInteger count = new AtomicInteger(1);
        pool.execute(new QuicksortRunnable<T>(numberArray, 0, numberArray.length - 1, count));

        try {
            synchronized (count) {
                count.wait();
            }
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }finally {
            pool.shutdown(); //call shutdown() here
            try {
                pool.awaitTermination(5, TimeUnit.MINUTES); //wait for 5 minutes
            }catch (InterruptedException ie) {
                ie.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    }
```

In the `finally` section call `shutdown()` to initiate a orderly shut down of the threads in the pool and as the `shutdown` call is not blocking the [`awaitTermination()`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/util/concurrent/ExecutorService.html#awaitTermination(long,java.util.concurrent.TimeUnit)) has to be called for the calling thread to wait for the shut down process to finish.

> Isn't 5 min to wait a bit too much?

The call to `awaitTermination` does not necessarily wait the full five minutes. The 5 minutes is the *maximum* time to wait, not the minimum. To quite the Javadoc:

> Blocks until all tasks have completed execution after a shutdown request, or the timeout occurs, or the current thread is interrupted, whichever happens first.

Comment: Thanks, that solved the problem for me. 
But I have one question. Isn't 5 min to wait a bit to much? Or is there a particular reason for that?
EDIT** And yeah, **great explenation**!

Comment: @MilanNikolić The 5 minutes is the *maximum* to wait, not the minimum.